# Dynamically added input fields not getting posted?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The code below consists of invoice-lines that contain some input fields that the user can fill out.  The initial number of input lines is 20. Users will often need to add more lines to the invoice by clicking the "Add lines" button. Every click of this button uses Javascript to append more lines to the invoice.

The problem is when the form gets submitted only the first 20 lines seem to get submitted. All the javascript appended invoice lines are ignored and never POSTed.

I have been trying to work out this problem for quite a while now, I was wondering if someone can guide me as to how to go about implementing this correctly?

Many thanks in advance.

Markup / PHP

```
      <?php
                for($i=0; $i < 20; $i++){
                    echo '
                    <div class="invoice-line">
                        <div class="prod-id-cell"><input name="rows['.$i.'][id]" type="text" class="prod-id-input">
                            <div class="smart-suggestions">
                                    <!-- RESULT SUGGESTIONS WILL POPULATE HERE -->                              </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="prod-name-cell">
                            <input type="text" name="rows['.$i.'][name]" class="prod-name-input"/>                                  <div class="smart-suggestions">
                                            <!-- RESULT SUGGESTIONS WILL POPULATE HERE -->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        <div class="price-cell"><input name="rows['.$i.'][price]" class="price-input" type="text" /></div>
                        <div class="quantity-cell"><input  name="rows['.$i.'][quantity]" type="text" class="quantity-input"></div>
                        <div class="unit-price-cell"><input name="rows['.$i.'][unit-price]" class="unit-price-input" type="text" /></div>
                        <div class="num-kits-cell"><input name="rows['.$i.'][num-kits]" class="num-kits-input" type="text" /></div>
                        <div class="amount-cell"><input name="rows['.$i.'][amount]" class="amount-input" type="text" readonly="readonly" /></div>
                    </div>';
                }
        ?>
```

Javascript

```
//**ADD 5 LINES**//
        $('.invoice-links div').on("click", ".add-five-trigger", function(){
            for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
                var invoiceLine = $(".invoice-line").first().clone( true, true );
                $(invoiceLine).insertAfter(".invoice-line:last");
                $(".invoice-line:last").find('input').val('').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Are you disabling this inputs?

Comment: Why do you set them to `disabled`? What enables them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to change the `name` attributes of the cloned inputs. They would overwrite previous fields.

Use this:

```
var invoiceLine = $(".invoice-line").last();
var newLine = invoiceLine.clone( true, true );
invoiceLine.after(newLine);
newLine.find('input').each(function() {
    if (this.type == "text")
        this.value = "";
    this.name = this.name.replace(/rows\[(\d+)\]/, function(m, num) {
        return "rows["+(+num+1)+"]";
    });
    this.disabled = true;
});
```

Comment: I have javascript to take care of disabled input fields. When users fill in the line above that is enabled, the closest line below it, that is disabled, becomes enabled automatically. How can I give unique ID's when fields are dynamically generated?

Comment: Instead of using .replace, I'd probably just set a variable in my javascript, and track the row number there, and then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to change the name.  Avoids the regex . . .

Answer (score 4):

The values are not being posted because you are disabling them. Input elements with disabled attribute don't get posted.

Also, always make sure that elements have unique ids and names. Elements without names don't get posted.

Comment: I have javascript to take care of disabled input fields. When users fill in the line above that is enabled, the closest line below it, that is disabled, becomes enabled automatically. How can I give unique ID's when fields are dynamically generated?

Comment: @MHZ then make sure that your dynamic input elements have names. The 2 reasons I listed are the only ones -that I can think of, at least- why an input element may not be submitted with a request.

Comment: @Icarus: Another possible reason: It was appended outside the form. Seems not to be the case here of course.

Comment: @Bergi Input fields are appended inside the form in my case, as they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving new names to the elements you create. You are also disabling them.

```
$(".invoice-line:last").find('input').val('').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Disabled form inputs will never be submitted with the form.